# Como limpar esse Deleted do git

Tags: git

Amigos eu tinha um arquivo no repositório local. Apaguei e ao dar o git status o historico está assim:

```
$ git  status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    testeGit.java
```

Como faço para limpar isso?deixar bonitinho, limpo. Não desejo mais o arquivo local, quero ele somente no github.

Answer (score 1):

Toda alteração que você fizer, seja adicionar novo arquivo, remover, editar..

```
git add -A
```

Depois faz o *Commit*

```
$ git commit -m "Arquivo removido testeGit.java"
```

Veja o *Estado*

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

> **Atualização**: Como comentado pelo @nunks-lol, usando o comando abaixo, poupa de usar o comando *git add -A*

```
git rm _arquivo_
```

Comment: Como o objetivo é colocar em "stage" a exclusão de um arquivo, pode também usar o `git rm _arquivo_` e "poupar" um `git add`...

Comment: Esse eu não sabia, pois quase não uso o *git*, vlw.

Comment: Eu sou da tribo dos puristas que falam: "usar `git add -A` é preguiça nociva". Não que deva ser evitado como o diabo foge da cruz, mas isso normalmente infringe conceitos como commits atômicos e uma melhor separação das mudanças do código. Um código devidamente commitado permite uma troca mais fácil de commits via `cherry-pick`, assim como fica mais fácil observar o processo usado na sua evolução para motivos de revisão e de histórico de código

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado estou sempre aprendendo aqui com vocês **:)**